# Search+replace strings in filenames

Tags: bash

Using bash, how can I search for all occurrences of the substring 'foo' in all filenames (including folders) contained recursively in a directory and replace them them with 'bar'?

For example, if the current structure looks like:

```
-foo_test
    - fooo.txt
    - xfoo
        - yfoo.h
- 1foo.c
```

It should look like this after running the bash script:

```
-bar_test
    - baro.txt
    - xbar
        - ybar.h
- 1bar.c
```

Comment: Will you need to worry about files containing foo twice? e.g. rename foo-foo.txt to bar-bar.txt

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Both variations shown here using work correctly on OPs test structure:

```
find . -depth -name '*foo*' -execdir bash -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1//foo/bar}"' bash {} \;
```

or, if you have a very large number of files and want it to run faster:

```
find . -depth -name '*foo*' -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv -i "$f" "${f//foo/bar}"; done' bash {} +
```

**EDIT**: As noted in the comments, my earlier answer using a `find` command that did not use the `execdir` option and using `rename` has problems renaming files in directories that contain foo in their name. As suggested, I have changed the find commands to use `-execdir`, and I have deleted the variation using the `rename` command since it is a non-standard command.

Comment: ... assuming you have the `rename` command, which is nonstandard.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a `g` in the regex if he can have foo multiple times? (that is `s/foo/bar/g`)

Comment: @triplee - And even worse, there are two different non-compatible variants that I see installed on different distros.

Comment: `for f in "$@";` can be shortened to `for f;` as `"$@"` is used by default in the absence of a list.  I'd use `-execdir` as it is both safer and because `mv path/foo/more/path/foo.txt path/bar/more/path/bar.txt` won't work.  See [BashFAQ 30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) for even more ideas.

Comment: I think you left out the "." after `find`. Also this doesn't work because it tries to change the directory and file name in *./foo_test/fooo.txt* at the same time: `mv: rename ./foo_test/fooo.txt to ./bar_test/baro.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hopefully fixed all problems mentioned in comments.  I went to the extreme measure of actually running the commands and they appeared to work.

Comment: @Adrian It still doesn't work here. Did you build the same structure the OP posted? I ran `find . -depth -name '*foo*' -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv -i "$f" "${f//foo/bar}"; done' bash {} +` but it chokes when the directory name and file name both contain "foo".

Comment: This is a cool solution but I may have been a bit too hasty in accepting it. I'll look into this further when i get a chance

Comment: @SSTeve: I Just tried it on the structure that OP posted and it worked.  See edit in my answer.

Comment: @SSTeve: But I see that the original attempt using `rename` without `-execdir` failed so I have deleted that from my answer.

Comment: +1. Note for anyone who this doesn't seem to work for. The file substrings are case sensitive. This tripped me up for a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

This was tricky because of <strike>directory</strike> names with multiple instances of "foo". When you change `./foo_test/xfoo` to `./bar_test/xbar` everything that was in `./foo_test` becomes inaccessible. So I changed the file names first then changed the last occurrence of "foo" in the directory names. I added echo statements to track what's going on during development. You can, of course, expunge them.

```
#!/bin/sh
#first change the file names
#append '.' to process files in current directory
for D in $(find -d . -name "*foo*" -type d ) '.' 
do 
    pushd $D >> /dev/null
    echo 'directory: ' "$D"
    for file in $(find . -name "*foo*" -type f -maxdepth 1)
    do
        echo '    change' "$file" 'to' `echo "$file" | sed s/foo/bar/g`
        mv "$file" `echo "$file" | sed s/foo/bar/g`
    done
    popd >> /dev/null
done

echo ''

#Now change the directory names
for D in $(find -d . -name "*foo*" -type d )
do 
    echo 'change' "$D" 'to' `echo "$D" | sed 's/\(.*\)foo/\1bar/'`
    #change only the last occurance of foo
    mv "$D" `echo "$D" | sed 's/\(.*\)foo/\1bar/'`
done
```

I have no doubt there are shorter, more elegant ways to do this (probably just by removing half of the lines in this script), but I'm pretty sure this works.

---

**EDIT**
The identical loops were a red flag. This version only loops once. You get a message attempting `mv '.' '.'`, but it's safely ignored.

```
#!/bin/sh
#first change the file names
#append '.' to change file in current directory
for D in $(find -d . -name "*foo*" -type d ) '.' 
do 
    pushd $D >> /dev/null
    echo 'directory: ' "$D"
    for file in $(find . -name "*foo*" -type f -maxdepth 1)
    do
        echo '    change' "$file" 'to' `echo "$file" | sed s/foo/bar/g`
        mv "$file" `echo "$file" | sed s/foo/bar/g`
    done
    popd >> /dev/null

    echo 'change' "$D" 'to' `echo "$D" | sed 's/\(.*\)foo/\1bar/'`
    #change only the last occurence of foo
    mv "$D" `echo "$D" | sed 's/\(.*\)foo/\1bar/'`
done
```