# Using Linux to recursively change file names?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a directory and files looking like this

```
/Folder/A/12 3ER This.docx
/Folder/A/12 3ER Namespace.docx
/Folder/A/12 QW Blah.docx
/Folder/A/12 QW BlahBlah.docx
/Folder/B/12 3ER Annoying.docx
/Folder/B/12 3ER Were.docx
/Folder/B/12 QW Stack.docx
/Folder/B/12 QW Overlow.docx
...
```

I want to rename all the files containing  `3ER`  to `_My_`

So the directory and files should look like

```
/Folder/A/12_My_This.docx
/Folder/A/12_My_Namespace.docx
/Folder/A/12 QW Blah.docx
/Folder/A/12 QW BlahBlah.docx
/Folder/B/12_My_Annoying.docx
/Folder/B/12_My_Were.docx
/Folder/B/12 QW Stack.docx
/Folder/B/12 QW Overlow.docx
...
```

How can I do this with Linux?

Comment: Questions about how to use your operating system, rather than questions about how to write software, are a better fit for [unix.se] SE or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). That said -- you might find [BashFAQ #30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) to be of interest; the only difference between what it demonstrates and what you need is the use of a different [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: This is arguably duplicative of [Search+replace strings in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171659/searchreplace-strings-in-filenames).

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '* 3ER *' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  mv -- "$filename" "${filename// 3ER /_My_}"
done
```